# One child padding affects all child padding in Linearlayout

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, material-design, android-linearlayout

I have two child in `LinearLayout`, the `LinearLayout` uses `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent` for width and height for `LayoutParameter`. The both child are `TextView` with `LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, parcentageOfChildWidth)`.
I added padding Top to the first child `TextView`, but doing that, the second child also gets the padding Top and push the content down.

[image]

I wonder whether there is a way to add padding Top to the first child and the rest child element stays as they are.
The first text view contains material icon, and the second one contains normal text.

Comment: What layout_gravity for TextViews and gravity for LinearLayout are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout1.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
linearLayout.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
textView1.Text = "TextView1";
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
layoutParams1.TopMargin = 15;   //set the top padding         
textView1.LayoutParameters = layoutParams1;
TextView textView2 = new TextView(this);
textView2.Text = "ABC17405";
linearLayout.AddView(textView1);
linearLayout.AddView(textView2);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers. This works nicely, but the icon can be invisible in my case and I need to keep the space when it is invisible too.

Comment: If you want it to keep the space when it is invisible,you just need set `textView1.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @Amin, for leading me to a right direction! Both layout_gravity and gravity were default value in both TextViews and LinearLayout. Changing the material icon's TextView's layout_gravity to be CenterHorizontal made padding top to work in the LinearLayout.

```
var param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, cell.PercentageWidth); 
param.Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal;
materialTextView.LayoutParameters = param;
materialTextView.SetPadding(0, 10, 0, 0);
```